# Replace colon in id with \\:

Tags: javascript, regex, salesforce, visualforce

The `id`'s on the page I'm working on are defined a group of colon-separated strings (e.g. `thisPage:theForm:address1content`). I can't change this format and I'm trying to do some validation on `address1content`.

I'm trying to pass the `id` for `address1content` to a function and do a `replaceAll` and replace the `:` with `\\:` so I can do a `$(id)`. It isn't working.

Here's what I have:

```
function validateContent(text) {

var hardCoded=$('#thisPage\\:theForm\\:address1content').val();
alert(hardCoded);

var regex = new RegExp(":", 'g');
replacedText = text.replace(regex, '\\:');  
alert(replacedText);
foundElement= $(replacedText).val();
alert(foundElement);    
}
```

Right now the variable `hardCoded` is coming through correctly but I'd like to be able to do this dynamically so I can validate multiple fields.

I pasted a simplified version in a fiddle if that helps: http://jsfiddle.net/nYeJH/

Comment: Unrelated to the question itself, but try using `console.log()` instead of `alert()`

Comment: Not sure if I get what you're trying to do here, but `'\\:' ---> '\:' ~-> ':'`if you need the double backslashes try this: `var foundElement= $(text.replace(/:/g,'\\\\:').val();`: 4 backslashes, each backslash should be doubled

Comment: .replace(/:/g,"\\:") seems to work fine for me. could you setup a jsfiddle?

Comment: @MicronXD: OP needs 2 backslashes, not 1

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem OP claims the hardcoded `'#thisPage\\:theForm\\:address1content'` works. look at the jsfiddle.   `.replace(/:/g,"\\:")` creates an exactly equal string to the one the OP claimed was working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Due to my comment, real reason was the forgotten `#` in the text.

http://jsfiddle.net/nYeJH/6

Answer (score 4):

K, since my comment actually answered the question (just read the title, and I get that you need all colons to be preceded by a double backslash), here's my answer:

```
var foundElement= $(text.replace(/:/g,'\\\\:').val();
```

4 backslashes: the first escapes the second, the thrid escapes the forth, the colon remains a colon, so.

That said, regular expressions are rather slow once you reach a certain number of occurrences of the substring. You should benchmark this but it might be marginally faster and (perhaps) easier to read to use split:

```
var foundElement = $(text.split(':').join('\\\\:')).val();//4 slashes still
```

Comment: I updated the fiddle but its not working, could you take a look? http://jsfiddle.net/nYeJH/3/

Comment: @turbo2oh take a look, you just forgot the `#` in the text http://jsfiddle.net/nYeJH/6/

Answer (score 0):

`.replace(/:/g,"\\:")` seems to work perfectly fine (assuming what you say about the hard-coded one is true). take a look at this jsfiddle.

if the hard-coded one isn't *actually* working, and you do need a double escaped `:`, try this `.replace(/:/g,"\\\\:")`

http://jsfiddle.net/SeNy5/

EDIT: now that you have a jsfiddle we can work with, I'm noticing you're accidentally leaving out the hash at the beginning of your CSS selector.

Comment: You're missing the hash at the beginning of your CSS selector.